# Write custom ribbonroutingfilter zuul for 1 route and default ribbonroutingfilter for rest of the zuul routes

Tags: ribbon, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-ribbon

I have a requirement where for 1 of the zuul route I have to use ssl certificate so the plan is to create a custom closeableHttpClient with the ssl configuration and use that in a custom ribbonroutingfilter while disabling the default ribbonroutingfilter for this 1 route, for all the other routes I want to skip the custom ribbonroutingfilter and use the default ribbonroutingfilter.

Can someone guide me with this requirement, or have a sample code that I can refer to
Thank you

I did some research and looks like I can inject a custom Closeable Httpclient bean but the problem is then the ssl certificate with will sent to all the zuul routes which is not I want